# Force ItemsControl to treat UiElements as data

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, itemtemplate, uielement, itemsource

How can I use on ItemTemplate on an ItemsControl whose Items is a list of UiElements?

Note : I know this is not the intended use, but it would be useful for debugging purposes

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow">
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    <Button Content="A" Name="TheButton"/>
    <CheckBox Content="AB" Name="TheCheckBox"/>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Post more code. Post us your complete xaml and viewmodel we can work on same source as you.

Comment: The code at the bottom sums up exactly what I want to do

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with sum up but in your question you are talking about owner ItemsControl holding a custom control and another inner ItemsControl. I cant see those in your "sum up" so I think you should just give us a demo or upload more code.

Comment: It's difficult to explain, but the code I gave does portray what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Ok cool sorry but I wasnt able to reproduce your issue. Its hard to reproduce anything here with that less code however if I would have to guess I would suggest you to take a treeview control instead of itemscontrol. ItemsControl inside ItemsControl worked in my example I just created. If you could anyhow give us more info or upload your project on github.com or anywhere else that would be great

Comment: I've edited the question with full example